# How to dynamic set element's class depending on Buefy breakpoint

Tags: vue.js, responsive, buefy

So I have been using [Buefy](https://buefy.org/) as an UI library for this new project and I come from a [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) background.

What I want to achieve using Buefy is this:

```
<div
  :class="{
    'ml-2': (condition to apply the class to mobile breakpoint)
  }"
>
...
```

In Vuetify I'd write the code like this:

```
<div
  :class="{
    'ml-2': $vuetify.breakpoint.mobile,
  }"
>
...
```

Is there an equivalent solution in Buefy?

Comment: I think you should remove vuetify from the tags as i totally misunderstood the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked Buefy's docs and it doesn't seem to have breakpoints feature.

You can instead do it yourself manually by creating a plugin or just add the following in your component:

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isMobile: false,
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1024px)');

    // Set initial value on first load.
    this.isMobile = !mediaQuery.matches

    // Listen for changes
    mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', event => {
      if (event.matches) {
        console.log('>= 1024px');
        this.isMobile = false;
      } else {
        console.log('< 1024px');
        this.isMobile = true;
      }
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: mediaQueryList should be called only mediaQuery (name of the const)

Comment: dont forget to remove event listener if need b